# Shopify user account creation require activation sometimes

Tags: shopify

We are building a custom Shopify website. Sometimes our custom sign up form will allow the user to login right away and other times it sends a "activate" account link. How is this managed? Did you experience that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've enountered this a few times and as far as I know it's based on the email address used to create the account.

If the email is not already in the store database then the customer will login straight away, but if a customer has used the same email address to place an order in the past for example and after that they decide to create an account, they'll get an email to activate their account.

Unfortunately, there's nothing you can do to change this flow.